# Integrate Google Place AutoCompleteAPI in Action bar Search?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have successfully Integrated `Google Place Autocomplete API` in `Activity`. New flow should be like this:

- User click on `Menu search` icon.
- Search box of `Google place autocomplete` should be align with it.
- Whatever user had choose from `autocomplete`. It should update the `Menu search Icon`.

Here is following code:

## Menu_item

```
...
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="always" />
...
```

## MainActivity

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_location, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.search) {
        // Method #3
        try {
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder
                    (PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                    .setBoundsBias(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW)
                    .build(AddLocationActivityNew.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException |
                GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Place Selected: " + place.getName());
    txt_location.setText(getString(R.string.formatted_place_data, place
            .getName(), place.getAddress(), place.getPhoneNumber(), place
            .getWebsiteUri(), place.getRating(), place.getId()));
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(place.getAttributions())){
        txt_attributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAttributions().toString()));
    }
}
```

Right now, I am clicking on menu item icon. It's opening a new activity: 
[image]

How can integrate this activity in action bar?

If I am changing the `MODE` from FullScreen to Overlays. It's something like this:

[image]

How Can I integrate the whole search bar in Android action bar?

Comment: not sure what you want but here is one [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_autocompletetextview_control.htm) please check that hope you will find some good stuff

Comment: @Nowshad I need to load the google map place autocomplete data in the given `adapter `

Comment: look at the example that i post in comment!

Comment: Try to add collapseactionview attribute to the menu item.app:showAsAction="always|collapseactionview"

Answer (score 0):

When you define the search button inside menu file, try to use `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`